# How to calculate coordinates to scroll window to icon center position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a webpage with tree of icons drawn on a canvas:
http://seznamka.moxo.cz/
You can move with the icons. My idea what I want to do is to center the view area of the window to the position of the icon.

For example, let's click and drag icon "Gothic" which is in the lower right corner when I open the page:

[image: Gothic in corner]

[image: Gothic in center]

The scroll should be made so, that the icon will be in the middle of screen but it should stay on its original position. So just the window should be moved to that location.

Here is the event which contains the windowScrollTo().

jQuery(canvas).mousemove(function(e) {
    var canvasPosition = jQuery(this).offset();
        var p = fromScreen({x: e.pageX - canvasPosition.left, y: e.pageY - canvasPosition.top});
        nearest = layout.nearest(p);

```
if (nearest.node.visible)
  {
  var s = toScreen(nearest.point.p);
  var h = e.pageX-canvasPosition.left > s.x ? e.pageX-canvasPosition.left - s.x : s.x - e.pageX-canvasPosition.left;
  var v = e.pageY-canvasPosition.top > s.y ? e.pageY-canvasPosition.top - s.y : s.y - e.pageY-canvasPosition.top;
  var distance = Math.sqrt(h*h + v*v);              
  underMouseEvent = distance <= iconRadius ? true : false;
  }
else
  underMouseEvent = false;

if (underMouseEvent )
  highlighted = nearest;

    if (dragged !== null && dragged.node !== null) {
        dragged.point.p.x = p.x;
        dragged.point.p.y = p.y;
 window.scrollTo(
 s.x
 // window.innerWidth/2     
 ,
 s.y
 // window.innerHeight/2
  );      
    }
    renderer.start();
});
```

I tried to just two variations s.x, s.y (coordinates of the icon which is dragged) and window.innerWidth/2,window.innerHeight/2 but not good result. How calculate the correct x and y position?

**Edit**
I have made change according suggestion. Now I add new version which includes condition to prevent annoying repeating when the icon is dragged. This way it will be called only once during drag. But another problem I found it that if I open pan(el) e.g Developers tools on side of brownser so there is some problem to center. I tried to correct the condition with left and right variables which should reflect the offset of current scroll but this is not fully working. Yet any ideas how to correct the calculation with scroll?

```
  jQuery(canvas).mousemove(function(e) {
    var canvasPosition = jQuery(this).offset();
        var p = fromScreen({x: e.pageX - canvasPosition.left, y: e.pageY - canvasPosition.top});
        nearest = layout.nearest(p);

    if (nearest.node.visible)
      {
      var s = toScreen(nearest.point.p);
      var h = e.pageX-canvasPosition.left > s.x ? e.pageX-canvasPosition.left - s.x : s.x - e.pageX-canvasPosition.left;
      var v = e.pageY-canvasPosition.top > s.y ? e.pageY-canvasPosition.top - s.y : s.y - e.pageY-canvasPosition.top;
      var distance = Math.sqrt(h*h + v*v);              
      underMouseEvent = distance <= iconRadius ? true : false;
      }
    else
      underMouseEvent = false;

    if (underMouseEvent )
      highlighted = nearest;

        if (dragged !== null && dragged.node !== null) {
            dragged.point.p.x = p.x;
            dragged.point.p.y = p.y;

     if (typeof s != 'undefined')
     {
     **var left = document.body.scrollLeft || window.pageXOffset;
     var top = document.body.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;**
     if ( releasedAfterDrag && 
          (
          s.x>window.innerWidth/2-**left** || 
          s.y>window.innerHeight/2-**top** 
          )
          )
      {
      window.scrollTo(
              s.x-window.innerWidth/2,
              s.y-window.innerHeight/2
              );
      console.log("dragging: " + releasedAfterDrag);
      }
     if (releasedAfterDrag)
      releasedAfterDrag = false;     
         }

    }
        renderer.start();
    });

    jQuery(window).bind('mouseup',function(e) {
        dragged = null;
    releasedAfterDrag = true;
    });
```

It seems to me that the new condition works correct only for the second half of the (inner) window (when the side panel is opened). So if the icon is in the top or right half the window is not centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this calculation to find its coordinates:
x: icon.x-window.innerWidth/2
y: icon.y-window.innerHeight/2

Comment: Thank you. This answer would be perfect if it would include how to set mouse position to correct the pointer to the location of icon. Is it possible to do it with JS? I did some search and I found that it is not possible to do it for security reasons, unless I read & understood that topic wrong.

Comment: You read right! Set the mouse position is not possible in js. P.s. can you make a jsfiddle for this code? That way it would be easier for others to help:)

Comment: no, the code is robust and complex, also not fixed fully, it has many bugs